# How to put Python loop output in a list

Tags: python

As a beginner to Python(SAGE) I want to put the output of this for loop 
into a list:

```
for y in [0,8] : 
   for z in [0,1,2,3] :
     x=y+z

     print x
```

The output is

```
0
1
2
3
8
9
10
11
```

(vertically). I want a list so I can use it for a later operation:
I want [1,2,3,8,9,10,11].
I found a similar question and I realize that the output is recalculated
each time. Is there a simple way to store them in a list? Following a suggestion for the other answer, I tried "append" like this, but it gives an error message:

```
x=[]
for y in [0,2*3] : 
 for z in [0,1,2,3] :
   x=y+z
   x.append(x)

  print x
```

Comment: You overwrote the name of the list. How is the interpreter supposed to know what you mean when you call everything `x`?

Comment: You're using the variable `x` for two different things:  the list and the calculated number.  Use it for only one of them and get an additional variable for the other. Like, `w = y + z` and then `x.append(w)`.

Comment: What do you mean by **Python(SAGE)**? If SAGE is an acronym, then there are quite a few ways to interpret it: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=what+does+the+acronym+SAGE+mean.

Comment: Thank you everyone very much for all your answers!!! I had just discovered something myself like sparc_spread's, and it works fine. But I will go through the other answers as well to learn something. It was really driving me crazy but that's how you learn!

Answer (score 12):

You have a lots of ways! First, as a raw code, you can do this:

```
lst=[]
for y in [0,8] : 
    for z in [0,1,2,3] :
        x=y+z
        lst.append(x)

print lst
```

You can try `list comprehension`:

```
lst = [y+z for y in [0,8] for z in [0,1,2,3]]
print lst
```

You can also use `itertool chain`:

```
import itertools  
lst = list(itertools.chain(*[range(i, i+4) for i in [0,8]]))
print lst
```

Another way is `itertool products`:

```
import itertools
lst = [y+z for y,z in list(itertools.product([0,8], [0,1,2,3]))]
print lst
```

In all cases, `output` is : `[0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11]`

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
lst = [y+z for y in [0,8] for z in [0,1,2,3]]
print(lst) # prints:  [1,2,3,8,9,10,11]
```

The reason your code did not work, is because your using the variable `x` for two different things. you first assign it to a list, then you assign it to a integer.
So python thinks that `x` is a integer, and integers don't have the attribute `append()`. Thus Python raise an error. The remedy is just to name your variables different things. But you should use something more descriptive than `x`, `y`,  and `z`, unless their 'throwaway' variables.

Answer (score 0):

Because you set variable `x` from `list` to `int` at this line: `x = y + z`.

`for`-loops don't have scopes like a function or class, so if you set a variable out of the loop, the variable is the same as if it were in the loop.

Comment: Do you mean **scope** when you say **myself space**?

Comment: Yes, the variable scope.

Comment: Do you mind if  I edit your answer to say that then? It's a little bit confusing what you mean when you say myself space.

Comment: Don't mind, i'm sorry that I didn't express it clearly.

Comment: Its cool. Just thought I might help you out, If I got what you were trying to say :)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
import itertools
temp = [y+z for y,z in list(itertools.product([0,8], [0,1,2,3]))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also approach this functionally using itertools.product:

```
from itertools import product

lst = [y + z for y, z in product([0, 8], [0, 1, 2, 3])]
print(lst)
```

will output `[0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11]`.

Comment: he does not have to use `itertools.product`. He can simply say: `lst = [y+z for y in [0,8] for z in [0,1,2,3]]`.

Comment: Fair enough, but I'm not really a fan of that syntax, almost feels like its gonna behave as `lst = [(y+z for y in [0,8]) for z in [0,1,2,3]]`. itertools.product is clearer imo and shouldn't make much of a difference performance wise.

Comment: My point was that the OP didn't have to import anything, he could just use the tools already in his files namespace. but to each his own I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
x = [y+z for y in [0,8] for z in [0,1,2,3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a list comprehension such as this one:

```
>>> lst = [y+z for y in [0,8] for z in [0,1,2,3]]
>>> lst
[0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

That's perfectly clear to any Python programmer.

Or you could use `range`:

```
>>> lst=[]
>>> for l in (range(i, i+4) for i in [0, 8]):
...     lst.extend(l)
>>> lst
[0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Or, since some seem to like complicated answers:

```
>>> import itertools  
>>> lst = list(itertools.chain(*[range(i, i+4) for i in [0,8]]))
>>> lst
[0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```